# Struts 2 - How to convert object list to string?

Tags: collections, types, struts2, converters

I'm learning Struts 2 and stucking on converting a list of object to string.

I have class Movie which has a list of Genre (`List<Genre>`) as its property. I want to show genre names of a movie as a string (each genre is separated by a comma). I have converted other classes to String successfully but none of them are arrays or collections.

My first attempt was writing a custom converter class with method `convertToString(Map map, Object obj)` but it didn't work:

```
if (obj instanceof List) {

    System.out.println("Found a list!");

                StringBuilder results = null;

                List list = (List) obj;

                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {

                    results = new StringBuilder();

                    // Genre List
                    if (list.get(0) instanceof Genre) {

                        System.out.println("Found a genre list!");

                        for (Object genre : list) {

                            results.append(((Genre) genre).getName() + ", ");
                        }

                    }
}
```

On JSP page:

```
<s:iterator value="movieList" status="movieStatus">
   ...
   <td>
        <s:property value="genres" />
   </td>
   ...
</s:iterator>
```

Then I tried another way:

```
if (obj instanceof Genre) {

            System.out.println("Found a genre!");

            return ((Genre) obj).getName();
}
```

JSP:

```
<td>
     <s:iterator value="genres" status="genreStatus">
           <s:text name="genres[#genreStatus.index]" />,&nbsp;
     </s:iterator>
</td>
```

or just this without converter:

```
<td>
     <s:iterator value="genres" status="genreStatus">
           <s:text name="genres[#genreStatus.index].name" />,&nbsp;
     </s:iterator>
</td>
```

And it didn't work either.

In both cases, Struts didn't jump into any `if` clauses or report any errors (`dev` mode was on). It just showed Genre objects' memory addresses (the first case) or `"genres[#genreStatus.index].name"` (the second) on the browser.

What did I miss here? Any responses would be appreciated!

Comment: Show the whole converter and why this is needed... if it is a one shot deal what is wrong with what you have done on the JSP? If you are trying to do this all over the place, have you considered ajax/json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need converter for that neither `<s:iterator>` tag. Just use [OGNL projections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Projecting_Across_Collections).

```
<s:property value="genres.{name}" />
```